# extracting zip files with powershell

Tags: powershell, zip

I am trying to extract a zip file to then be downloaded by remote people.  Once extracted I will have a script that installs the package but I need to use a compressed folder and the remote users don't have 7zip or anything like it.

I have this but I keep getting an error -

```
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$zip = $shell.NameSpace(“C:\name.zip”)
foreach($item in $zip.items())
{
$shell.Namespace(“C:\temp\name”).copyhere($item)
}
```

The error I am getting is below -

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:5 char:43
+ $shell.Namespace(“C:\name”).copyhere <<<< ($item)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (copyhere:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

There are other issues with the code but this is a work in progress, I will fix the hard coding of values once I can get it to extract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your extract path exist (“C:\temp\name”)? To be clear, both of the items in that path should be directories.

That should be a path that already exists. If it doesn't you get that error.

Comment: Well I feel like quite the n00b now.  It works just fine.  Thanks for that, I am going to make it a function now.